# Need Help Turning a Product into Closed Form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So for a counting question regarding how many functions are possible such that $n\times r$ items maps to $n$ containers with each container having $r$ items. The functions must also be surjective. I have obtained the following number of possible functions.

$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{(n-i)*k)}{k}$

How can I turn this expression into something in closed form?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would say that this is as closed-form as it can get. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{(n-i)k}{k} &=\binom{k}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\cdots \binom{nk}{k}\\
&=\frac{k!}{k!}\frac{[2k]!}{k!k!}\cdots\frac{[nk]!}{k![(n-1)k]!}\\
&=\frac{[nk]!}{(k!)^n}
\end{align*}
To get the result on the last line, notice that the numerator of each fraction cancels with a factor in the denominator of the next.